# changing nginx conf file

Tags: docker, nginx, openresty

I installed openresty alpine docker image and mounted conf.d to define the server in there. It works  fine.

Next,  I want to change nginx.conf and set `worker_process=auto`.  However  `worker_processes` are defined in  nginx.conf. I tried to volume mount `nginx.conf` in  Docker-compose file as:

```
volumes:
 -  ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d  
 -  ./conf/nginx.conf:/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

however, it creates a directory `nginx.conf`  in `./conf`

How can I  mount/modify nginx.conf?

Answer (score 3):

You are mounting it with the wrong directory of the Docker if you want to update nginx root configuration.

**Nginx Config Files**

> The Docker tooling installs its own `nginx.conf` file. If you want to
>   directly override it, you can replace it in your own Dockerfile or via
>   volume bind-mounting.
>
> For the Linux images, that nginx.conf has the directive include
>   `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf`; so all nginx configurations in that
>   directory will be included. The default virtual host configuration has
>   the original OpenResty configuration and is copied to
>   `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.

```
docker run -v /my/custom/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d openresty/openresty:alpine
```

Second thing, Better to use an absolute path for mounting.

```
docker run -v $PWD/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf openresty/openresty:1.15.8.2-1-alpine
```

or

```
docker run -v abs_path/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf openresty/openresty:1.15.8.2-1-alpine
```

**Openresty config:**

```
docker run -v $PWD/conf/nginx.conf:/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf openresty/openresty:1.15.8.2-1-alpine
```

You should mount exact file, otherwise it will break the container.

[image]
here is the default config for `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`

```
# nginx.conf  --  docker-openresty
#
# This file is installed to:
#   `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`
# and is the file loaded by nginx at startup,
# unless the user specifies otherwise.
#
# It tracks the upstream OpenResty's `nginx.conf`, but removes the `server`
# section and adds this directive:
#     `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`
#
# The `docker-openresty` file `nginx.vh.default.conf` is copied to
# `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.  It contains the `server section
# of the upstream `nginx.conf`.
#
# See https://github.com/openresty/docker-openresty/blob/master/README.md#nginx-config-files
#

#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: $PWD does not work for me but I can live with the relative path for now as it still works fine. However, I still can not mount /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf     I revised the question with the  entries from my docker-compose file

Comment: I upated the asnwer with screen shot it working fine. which OS you are using?

Comment: Linux mint.  Are  you volume mounting /etc/nginx/nginx.conf  or /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf ? Your answer has both.  Please note that /etc/nginx/nginx.conf  does not exist in my container. If you see my docker-compose, I did vol. mount  /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

Comment: seems like you are using different tag of the iamge. try with `openresty/openresty:1.15.8.2-1-alpine`

Comment: I am using openresty/openresty:1.15.8.2-1-alpine but the  problem  still exists.  Are  you volume  mounting   /etc/nginx/nginx.conf or /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf ?

Comment: I am mounting `usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`, make sure it on host OS